# How do I store task results to DB from Celery clients code also?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, flower

I am trying hands on to get the hang of Celery. So far everything looks fine. I am just not able to figure out one thing:

I want the task results being stored in DB to have states updated not only from workers, but from the client application too, when the message is being sent to broker.

So currently I have the below two lines in my configuration:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
```

This updates all the states for tasks inside DB that are managed by worker, including the `STARTED` state.

But what I want is to also have the states that are due to client side, like `PENDING`. So that the results in DB starts with `PENDING` as long as the worker doesn't get that task and then when the worker starts/gets that task, the states like `STARTED`, `SUCCESS` etc. are updated to database.

Rationale behind is we want our database to have records for all the tasks, even if they are still in pending state (i.e. not yet picked by any workers).

My question is:

1. Is it possible? Because this way the task row in DB has to be created by client code and then worker when updating the task states has to identify the correct task. May be if not by any Celery config, then by writing a custom code?
2. I came across `CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT = True` which enables Celery clients to send the events which in turn allows `Flower` to show `PENDING` tasks. My guess was that if `Flower` can get these events from client code and then later update the correct status from events from worker, so does the database should be able to do. Tried above setting to just give it a try. But not only it didn't work for database, it also had no effect on `Flower` too. I still do not see my pending tasks on `Flower`. I can only see them when the worker starts and changes their states.

Comment: Beware, "PENDING" may not mean what you think, cf the doc: "Task state is unknown (assumed pending since you know the id)." - and indeed if you pass a bogus task_id to `AsyncResult` that's what you will get. (NB : yes I know it doesn't answer your question, just wanted to warn you).

Comment: wrt/ Flower, you may want to read the source code, IIRC it gets the task list from the broker's queue directly, it doesn't read them from the result backend.

Comment: yeah, have read about what `PENDING` _actually_ means. Still, the question exists.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, Flower doesn't/can't? get data from broker's queue. It captures the events sent by workers (and events sent by client as per docs of `CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT`, that apparently didn't work for me)